# update text in multiple html pages from a master js file

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a website with multiple pages. Each page has one section with exactly the same text that I would like to be able to update on a regular basis from a master .js file which I have called; my_info.js

To reference that file I have then placed the following code into an .html page of my website in between the `<head></head>` tags;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_info.js"></script>
```

And that's all she wrote! I have no idea what code I need in the my_info.js file. Nor do I know what code to place within the actual .html pages where I want to display the text from the my_info.js file

This seems such a simple idea I'm sure it must be possible but I've searched the web and I can't find an example/tutorial anywhere. When you are answering it's safe to assume that I'm pretty dumb so don't worry about over simplifying things! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use JavaScript to select the element on the page and set the text of that element. Check out the example below.

EDIT: You'll also need to place your `<script type="...>` code at the **bottom** of your `<body>` element just before the closing tag (not in the `<head>`) because you want the page to render all the elements before you try and select one with JS.

```js
// my_info.js

// Get the element
var element = document.getElementById('some-id')

// Set the inner text
element.innerText = 'This text was inserted by JS'
```

```html
<div id="some-id">This text will get overwritten by JS</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All working fine now. I'm always very impressed by folks like your good self who are willing to give up their own time to help others. Take a bow sir. Thanks again

Comment: Quick follow up. What if I wanted to write more than one paragraph? How do I start new lines and put in breaks? Thanks

Comment: Just so I don't waste your valuable time I've sorted this like;

// Set the inner text
element.innerText = 'This text was inserted by JS\r\n\r\n'
element.innerText += 'New Paragraph\r\n\r\n'
element.innerText += 'And another one'

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should placed <script type="....> in between ...body> not in head tag